# How to correctly select count of grouped values for unique users from MYSQL table (see example)

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have `MySQL` table 'orders' with following structure (removed some fields for this example for simplicity):

**userid** (user placed order)

**payment_type** (Can be A, B or C for example)

I need to make `SQL query` that will return me array of users counts for each payment method used for orders. So I will know something like this:

**Payment method A - was used by 10 people**

**Payment method B - was used by 25 people**

**Payment method C - was used by 13 people**

Note - I don't need to know orders counts with payment methods, I need to know how many unique users used every payment method.

I used this SQL but as I see it does not sum counts to show correct results and I don't know how to sum it correctly in SQL:

```
SELECT payment_type, count(*) AS value FROM orders GROUP BY user_id
```

Please help with correct SQL query.

Comment: `SELECT payment_type, count(distinct user_id) AS value FROM orders GROUP BY payment_type`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks so much! This is what I am looking for. Forgot about distinct ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PaulSpiegel , this is correct code for this:

```html
SELECT payment_type, count(distinct user_id) AS value FROM orders GROUP BY payment_type
```